# Using existing .net libraries in JavaScript/HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime

My company has an enterprise solution with a huge code base most of it is developed using C# and VB.NET with some C++. We are now considering creating an app for Windows 8 Store app (probably in JavaScript/HTML5 as we don't have developers with wpf/xaml expereince but have some great developers with wealth of experience in these JavaScript/CSS etc). We would like to us some of our existing code libraries that are written in C#, VB.NET, C++. So far what I have read is that existing .NET libraries could not be called directly from a Windows 8 Store app and will require to create Windows 8 component. Is this correct? Can we creating these reusable components using JavaScript? If some one can provide recommendation on useful links with sample that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible to create a HTML/JS app for Windows 8 which also uses C# and C++ components.  The only caveat is that the C# and C++ component have to be written as [Windows Runtime Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441572%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).  Visual Studio through its various project templates etc. makes it very easy to create Windows Runtime components, in which then you can wrap your existing code.  See [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Raman-Sharma-Building-Metro-Style-Apps-with-C-and-JavaScript) and [this](http://blendinsider.com/technical/creating-an-html-metro-style-app-that-references-c-and-c-code-2012-04-13/) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this application, for converting .NET assemblies to JS code: https://github.com/sq/JSIL

This site has a huge list of apps for converting lots of different languages to JS: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS